# MutationObserver to remove a div when style changes

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to remove a div when the style changes. I have read that MutationObserver can do this. But the code that I tried is not working.

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(function
(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        if (mutation.attributes === 'style') {
            removeDiv()
        }
    })
})

const elem = document.querySelector('.show-pl');
observer.observe(elem, {
    attributes: true
})

function removeDiv() {
    Object.assign(elem.style, {
        display: 'none',
    })
}
```

Comment: The code you've tried doesn't use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) at all.

Comment: Ye I know. I haven't added the code because it's not right. Only the element that needs to be removed when it's loaded on the page.

Comment: Always show your attempt to solve the problem. Then we can help you understand why it didn't work.

Comment: Ah oke. I have added the code and rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of a new element has nothing to do with attributes, and you can't observe mutations on an element that isn't in the DOM yet.

Instead, you look for `childList` modifications on the parent element the `div` will be added within (or `childList` + `subtree` on an ancestor, if you can't watch the parent directly —if necessary, the ancestor can even be `document.body`).

Here's an example watching the parent directly:

```js
// Set up the observer on the container
let observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    // Does the div exist now?
    const div = document.querySelector(".show-pl");
    if (div) {
        // Yes, "remove" it (you're really just hiding it) and release this observer
        console.log("The div has appeared, hiding and releasing observer");
        div.style.display = "none";
        observer.disconnect();
        observer = null;
    }
});
observer.observe(document.getElementById("the-parent"), {
    childList: true
});
console.log("Watching for the element");

// On a delay, create the div
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Creating the div");
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = "Hi there!";
    div.className = "show-pl";
    document.getElementById("the-parent").appendChild(div);
}, 800);
```

```html
<div id="the-parent"></div>
```

To watch an ancestor instead you'd use the ancestor in the `observe` call and add `subtree: true` to the init options.

Comment: Hi T.J. Sorry for the late comment. 

It makes more sense. When I use the code, the div .show-pl will be replaced by the created div with the same class.

The code doesn't do the trick for me. 
.show-pl shows up in the DOM when the user clicks on a button. This code only works when .show-pl is there from the beginning.

Comment: @LauraV6 - The live example above shows it working when the `.show-pl` element *isn't* there from the beginning, so I think you must have applied it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDiv(canvas) { 
    var elem = document.querySelector('.show-pl');
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, me) {
  var canvas = document.querySelector(".show-pl");
  if (canvas) {
    removeDiv(canvas);
    me.disconnect();
    return;
  }
});

observer.observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

This does what I want, but an error occurs "cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null", because the div doesn't exists in the DOM yet.